# Gdal does not honor proj.4 scaling factor "+k_0"

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, proj

## My problem:

I'm currently trying to use `gdal` to write GeoTIFF files. I'm however having problems with using a proj4 string to describe the projection. ("+proj=lcc **+k_0=0.001** +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +no_defs"). Essentially the scaling factor "+k_0" is ignored by gdal.
I know that instead of `+k_0`, I can use `dataset->SetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform)` (in C++) and set this value manually. However I am surprised that doing this via the proj4 string does not seem to be possible.

If you try the following in python:

## Example:

```
from gdal import osr
p = osr.SpatialReference()
p.ImportFromProj4("+proj=lcc +k_0=0.001 +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +no_defs")
print p.ExportToProj4()
```

the output simply drops the `+k_0` parameter:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs
```

This results in completely different projected coordinates however and makes it difficult to rely onto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value for `+k_0` should be around 1.0. See the table at Snyder, Map projections, page 110. You may find the source code for lcc at https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/browser/trunk/proj/src/PJ_lcc.c

If you intend to use units different from meters, use `+units` or `+to_meter` instead.

---

Testing with cs2cs on `1000 1000`:

```
echo k=1 m >out.txt
cs2cs +proj=lcc +k_0=1 +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.9f" lcc-in.txt >>out.txt
echo k=0.001 m >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=lcc +k_0=0.001 +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.9f" lcc-in.txt >>out.txt
echo k=1 mm >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=lcc +k_0=1 +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +units=mm +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.9f" lcc-in.txt >>out.txt
echo k=1 to-meter >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=lcc +k_0=1 +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +to_meter=0.001 +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.9f" lcc-in.txt >>out.txt
echo k=0.9 m >>out.txt
cs2cs +proj=lcc +k_0=0.9 +lat_1=46 +lat_2=49 +lat_0=47.5 +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +no_defs +to +init=epsg:4326 -f "%%.9f" lcc-in.txt >>out.txt
```

delivering:

```
k=1 m 
13.341301026    47.505398796 0.000000000
k=0.001 m 
22.172450742    52.582612826 0.000000000
k=1 mm 
13.328035167    47.496409491 0.000000000
k=1 to-meter 
13.328035167    47.496409491 0.000000000
k=0.9 m 
13.342186463    47.505998628 0.000000000
```

---

The [EPSG Guidance 7-2](http://www.iogp.org/pubs/373-07-2.pdf) lists a 2SP Michigan variant of lcc, using a scale factor **and** 2 parallels. The factor seems to scale the ellipsoid. In the proj definitions for EPSG 4268 and 26811 to 26813, this is been done by scaling a and b (ignoring the NAD27 datum shift to WGS84). Using `+k_0=1.0000382` on the original ellipsoid returns the same values, as given in the Guidance.

See http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2015-April/007108.html for the discussion on that.

Comment: Ok. It seems the answer to my question is really: "Not every string that works in proj.4 is valid in gdal." The `+to_meter` seems to be what I was actually looking for when trying out `+k`

Comment: Why do you think that it **works** in proj.4?  I assume wrong parameters are dropped silently.

Comment: Because if I transform some coordinates (with the proj.4 api) using the string *with* "+k=0.001", I get the same coordinates as *without*, only scaled by a factor of 1e3. So adding `+k=0.001`  changes the result, which is what I was expecting to happen also in gdal, but there both *with* and *without* yield the same coordinates.

Comment: If I use Proj.4 cs2cs to convert from your lcc to EPSG:4326, k=0.001 and +to_meter=0.001 deliver different coordinates. The first one is totally off. See my extended answer.

Comment: I was actually comparing the following two definitions: **with +k:** `"+proj=lcc +lat_1=46N +lat_2=49N +lat_0=47.5N +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400 +y_0=400 +k=0.001 +no_defs"` and **with +to_meters**
`"+proj=lcc +lat_1=46N +lat_2=49N +lat_0=47.5N +lon_0=13.333333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=400000 +y_0=400000 +to_meters=1000 +no_defs"`. Using proj4 they are equivalent. Using gdal they are not (because `+k` is not supported.) I agree with you that `units` is the better way to solve this problem.

Comment: From http://proj.maptools.org/gen_parms.html:  `Virtually all coordinate systems allow for the presence of a false easting (+x_0) and northing (+y_0). Note that these values are always expressed in meters even if the coordinate system is some other units.`

Answer (score 4):

By reading the documentation https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/NetCDF_ProjectionTestingStatus and looking at the note about lcc it seems that +k_0 is not supported and defaults to 1 always.

> Lambert conformal 1SP / 2SP
>
> The 1SP variant corresponds to EPSG code 9801 - Lambert Conic
>   Conformal (1SP), with CF
>   latitude_of_projection_origin=standard_parallel and WKT
>   scale_factor=1. A scale factor less than 1 means that there are 2
>   standard parallels (see
>   www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/lambert_conic_conformal_1sp.html),
>   but it cannot be translated to the CF 1SP variant, therefore the 2SP
>   variant should be used instead. The 2SP variant corresponds to EPSG
>   code 9802 - Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP).

BTW. Links to remotesensing.org do not work, someone else has taken the domain name. Use web.archive.org instead.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160305172849/http://remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/lambert_conic_conformal_1sp.html

https://web.archive.org/web/20160305140706/http://remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/lambert_conic_conformal_2sp.html.

Comment: So this means that not every valid proj.4 string can be used as a gdal-`OGRSpatialReference`?

Comment: Ok. I was expecting `+k` to work, because if you use it in proj.4 alone, it does correctly scale using the given value. However it seems that even though proj.4 does not a have a problem combining LCC-2SP and +k, gdal does.

Comment: Probably you understand it better, but by reading the links above I concluded that 2SP does not support +k_0 at all, and if +k_0 is used with 1SP it means  effectively a conversion into 2SP with two properly set standard parallels.

Comment: Yes, the links describe gdal's behaviour when using proj4 strings. You are right that what I was trying to do is simply not supported by gdal. What threw me off however is, that if you use the proj.4 API directly, the parameter `+k` *is* supported.

Comment: But even if it is supported, is is the correct way for converting millimeters to meters if that was your real need?

Comment: I could not really find any documentation on this, so as the result was correct, I assumed it would be fine. But as AndreJ pointed out: `+to_meter` is probably a better alternative.

Comment: @user30184 the content of remotesensing.org has been moved to http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/lambert_conic_conformal_1sp.html